# Rodapé "grudado" no fim da página e responsivo (altura variável - usando bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Venho acompanhando questões similares aqui na stackoverflow e nos outros sites da rede, além de tutoriais na internet, mas a grande maioria das soluções não funcionam como eu preciso, ou mesmo são incompatíveis com o sistema do bootstrap.

Busco uma forma de "grudar" o rodapé no final da página, com altura variável (muda conforme o viewport e a disposição do grid interno), responsiva e com suporte ao bootstrap atual (3.4.4). Vale inclusive javascript puro e/ou jquery.

Isso é possível?

Comment: Possível é, `position:absolute; bottom:0`. Já tentou alguma coisa? Se sim, [edite](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/63253/edit) a pergunta inclua o código.

Comment: Alguma das soluções solucionou o problema? se sim valide uma.

Comment: @renan tive alguns problemas com a sua solução: Usando apenas essas 2 propriedades me dá um footer que fica no fim da tela, mas ao mudar a resolução fica como está no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vpontin/jtpduw71/).

Comment: [Fiz mais uns testes no Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vpontin/9ytwxea3/), e percebi que tenho uma faca de duas pontas agora.
Esse snippet é bem o que eu quero, PORÉM agora o problema é com o atributo "position". Quando há pouco conteúdo, usar "absolute" funciona como eu quero (está como eu quero no fiddle).
Porém [quando há muito conteúdo](http://jsfiddle.net/vpontin/o45ky4sy/) (quando extravasa a altura da janela), o absolute faz com que o conteúdo "passe por trás" do rodapé e ele continue fixo no fundo da tela (não de toda a página).
Se eu trocar os valores do position, não dá certo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Editado** Segue um exemplo, para testar faça o seguinte, deixa sua janela pequena ( do tamanho de uma tela de de celular(para simular um dispositivo móvel), e carregue o código abaixo, depois deixe maximizado e carregue a página novamente, verá que o footer(rodapé) fica sempre "grudado" no final da "janela"

```js
var principal = {};

principal.start = function(){
  $('#footer').css('position','static');
};

$(window).scroll(function(){   
  //var s = $(document.body)[0].scrollHeight;
  var h = $(window).height();
  s > h ? $('#footer').css('position','static') : $('#footer').css('position','fixed');;
  //$('#footer').css('top',h-42); // CASO PRECISE DESCONTAR O NAVBAR
  $('#footer').css('top',h); // PARA FIXAR O FOOTER NA PARTE INFERIOR DA PAGINA
});

principal.start();
```

```css
#footer {
            
            margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
            padding: 0px 0 0 0;
            text-align: center;
            position: static;
            width: 100%;
            
            }
    .fixed { position: fixed; }
    .static { position: static; }
    #footer-left {
            color: #FFFFFF;  
            font-size: 11px;
            line-height: 11px;
            padding: 10px 0 10px 0px;
            border-top: 5px solid #A5151E;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
            background: #2A2A2A;    
            height: 12px;
            
            } 
    #footer-left a {
            color: #FFFFFF;
            text-decoration: none;
            }
    #footer-left   a.selected,
    #footer-left   a:hover {
            color: red;
            text-decoration: none;
            }
            #conteudo{ height: 300px; width: 100%; background: yellow; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
 <title>Sistemas BTR - Transportes</title>                
    </head>
    
<body>         
    <div class="nav-outer-repeat" >
        <ul id="nav" class="nav-outer">            
            <div style="float: right;">                
            </div>            
        </ul>
    </div>        
    <div id="content-outer"><div id="conteudo"> corpo do texto</div></div>
    <!--<div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>-->
    <div id="barraMin" style="height: 0px; overflow-x: auto;" ></div>
    <div id="footer">        
        <div id="footer-left">                            
            <div id="link" style="text-align: center; ">RODAPÉ                   
            </div>                 
        </div>                 
    </div>
    
    <script>
              
    </script>
</body>    
</html>
```

Comment: Fiz um teste nesse e não funcionou
[Print](http://puu.sh/hL9E2/21155f583e.jpg)

Comment: @Vico poste seu código fonte junto na pergunta, assim posso dar uma olhada e ajusta-lo para que fique como no exemplo que passei acima

Comment: Opa! Desculpe, não usava o JSFiddle ainda.
Aí está ("juntei" o meu código pré-existente com o seu rodapé) [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h8y4ucw6/)

Comment: oi @Vico voce que o rodapé fique grudado no final da pagina, e esta, a pagina HTML termina, e "grudado" nele esta o rodapé, agora me avisa ai se entendi errado

Comment: @Vico você quer colar o rodapé no final da janela? de forma que em qualquer resolução (responsivo) ele fique sempre no grudado no final da janela? é isso?

Comment: Exatamente!
Eu perguntei aqui no stack porque ninguém sabe uma forma de fazer isso levando em conta que, conforme a quantidade de conteúdo lá, o tamanho do rodapé muda conforme a página é aberta em diferentes dispositivos.

Por exemplo, em telas pequenas o bootstrap "acomoda" o conteúdo e por isso a altura fica maior. Por isso eu não consigo usar as snippets com altura-fixa.

Comment: Opa, acabei me embananando na resposta acima.
@SneepSNinjA é o seguinte:
Quero grudar o rodapé no fim da janela CASO não haja conteúdo suficiente nos elementos acima dela para mandá-la pra baixo "naturalmente".
Se tiver, deixar ela no fim da página mesmo.

Comment: [Uma imagem vale mais que mil palavras...](http://puu.sh/hPTXb/29e06bff0a.png)

Comment: @Vico vou editar minha resposta com esse link ai ficou bem claro o problema.

Comment: [Atualizei o Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vpontin/wgqjt5nd/), continua "indo pra cima" quando há pouco conteúdo na tela...

Comment: @Vico nesse teste acho melhor usar uma pagina de teste em seu ambiente de teste local mesmo (rede), testei aqui na minha máquina e funciona

Comment: Fiz algumas modificações no código do javascript e [coloquei na minha pasta pública no DropBox](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/251493929/testes/teste_03.htm)

Comment: [Fiz algumas modificações no código e deu nisso aqui](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/251493929/testes/teste_04.htm). Troquei os heights por Outerheight porque ai engloba padding e margin dos elementos. A princípio está do jeito que eu queria (vou marcar a resposta inclusive, muito obrigado), hoje a noite irei testar colocando elementos do bootstrap no rodapé, para ver se pode dar conflito.

Comment: Bom, estou com outros problemas agora, relacionados à função outerHeight retornar valores aleatórios para a altura do conteúdo, fazendo com que algumas vezes o rodapé fique "preso" no meio do conteúdo.
[A pergunta está aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/64609/jquery-retornando-diferentes-valores-em-outerheighttrue), eu criei essa nova pois acho que fugiu do escopo desta aqui.

De qualquer forma, muito obrigado pela resposta!

Answer (score 5):

@Vico se deseja que o navbar fique preso ao final da página este `HTML` do bootstrap poderá ajuda-lo (Derivado de uma pergunta igual a sua do [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20905185/create-a-fixed-to-bottom-navbar-in-bootstrap-that-slides-content-upwards-when-to)):

```html
<footer>
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="footer-body">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="#">Browse Our Library</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Our Partners</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">User Review</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Terms &amp; Conditions</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
               <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#footer-body">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="footer-bar-btns visible-xs">
                        <li><a href="#" class="btn" title="History"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-clock-o blue-text"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="btn" title="Favourites"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-star yellow-text"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="btn" title="Subscriptions"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-rss-square orange-text"></i></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
    
            </div>
        </div>

</footer>
```

poderá vê-lo a rodar aqui: [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/117444)

Como fica no bootply:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: não consegui ver o Bootply,(cliquei em run e nao aconteceu nada) tem como executar aqui mesmo no SO para darmos uma olhada

Comment: @SneepSNinjA, esta tudo certo no bootply, você esta vendo uma barra com os seguintes botões no rodapé da página: Browse Our Library, About Us, Contact Us, Our Partners ... esta é a barra, não sei como executar código direto no SO.

Comment: alterei seu post para executar aqui no SO, no link que você passou não consigo visualizar esse barra com os links.

Comment: @SneepSNinjA qual o botão que devo acessar para ter codigo executando aqui? o código não executa quando parcial (o meu caso). adicionei o print do bootply.

Comment: Do lado do Adicionar Imagem quando estiver editando o post, tem uma tecla de atalho também Ctrl + M

Comment: Achei interessante essa solução, porém pelo fato de aparecer tanto a navbar de cima quanto a do rodapé, pode dificultar a visão de quem usa telas pequenas.

Comment: @Vico esta solução adiciona somente `1` `navbar` o pintado de vermelho na imagem.

Comment: @RicardoHenrique e a do topo também

Comment: @vico não é criado uma no topo com este código.

Comment: Ah sim @RicardoHenrique, me desculpe pelo erro (é que o Bootply usa o bootstrap também :P
Mas é que eu pretendo usar a navbar no topo também, e ter duas fixas no topo e embaixo iria diminuir demais a area visivel de conteudo em mobiles. Esse é o meu problema...

Answer (score 1):

Independente do tamanho do conteúdo, se o tamanho do *footer* for fixo (i.e., `height: 150px` ou algo assim, esta técnica é uma das melhores que já vi. Chama-se [Sticky Footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/)

Comment: Essa do Ryan Fait eu já vi e é muito boa mesmo, PORÉM pra quem usa o bootstrap e layout responsivo não dá pra contar com um valor de altura fixo, pois em cada viewport o texto é recondicionado.

Comment: Ele existe integrado com a versão 2.3.2 do bootstrap: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/examples/sticky-footer.html

Comment: O problema é que essa é uma solução para uma versão antiga do Bootstrap (2.3.2, e eu estou usando a 3.3.4), e [conforme o meu teste](http://jsfiddle.net/vpontin/zdb58f6f/) dá problema ao redimensionar o viewport e/ou adicionar mais conteúdo (a background nao preenche todo o rodapé).

Comment: isso é estranho. deveria funcionar. eu vou dar uma estudada aqui